# Is mysql automatically compressing the database?

Tags: mysql

My table entry was pretty long , around 10000 characters , so i'm wondering if i need to compress that myself , e.g use gzip library , before inserting to `mysql` ?

Current i'm using MyISAM database format.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the attributes `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED, KEY_BLOCK_SIZE`, or both in the `CREATE TABLE` and `ALTER TABLE` statements to enable table compression. Depending on the combination of option values, `InnoDB` attempts to compress each page

For more details go through below link:

[Enabling Compression for a Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-compression-usage.html)

Answer (score 2):

`InnoDB` support data compression:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-compression-usage.html

Answer (score 0):

The *mysqlclient* library may do some compression (with `CLIENT_COMPRESS` flag to [mysql_real_connect](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-real-connect.html)) to minimize network bandwidth, but AFAIK the `mysqld` server program won't compress data on disk, unless asked (see [Moshe's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8693082/841108)). And you probably don't want to search inside compressed data.

BTW, you should use InnoDB not MyISAM (which is sort-of deprecated).

Comment: Your response is useful if the client and the MySQL server is on WAN, and the problem is network latency/speed, not HDD.

Answer (score 0):

To Enable compression on table you need to follow the below steps.

1)Need to set parameter in mysqlconfig file

`SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=1;`
`SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;`

2)Need to add clauses

`ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED or KEY_BLOCK_SIZE` on create or alter table command.
you can use any of this they are optional.
`ALTER TABLE node ROW_FORMAT=compressed;`