# Compressing data stored in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, compression, myisam

We store full html pages in our table in a field called 'conteny'. Now this table is like an archive and we would be rarely using it. The 'content' field is of type 'longtext' right now and I would like to know which is the best way we could compress and keep this table's data as its taking many gbs of space.

I tried simply using the gzcompress function on the content field in php but that did not work.e.g.

```
 $content = gzcompress($content,9);
```

Also tried this but does not work:

```
update posts_content set content = COMPRESS(content)
```

Any ideas whats the best way to do it and how?

Another question here [Is mysql automatically compressing the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693056/is-mysql-automatically-compressing-the-database) talks about INNODB but we use MYISAM and could move to INNODB as a final resort.

Thanking you

Comment: Take a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228950/compressing-text-before-storing-it-in-the-database

Comment: If the field type is TEXT, then the compressed binary data is likely getting corrupted by character set conversions. Use a BLOB type to store raw binary data - they're not subject to charset conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using compression the result is binary not text. You shouldn't try to store the result in a text column. A `BLOB` column should work with the `gzcompress` method.